# Flume: Send files to HDFS via APIs

Tags: hadoop, cloud, flume

I am new to Apache Flume-ng. I want to send files from client-agent to server-agent, who will ultimately write files to HDFS. I have seen http://cuddletech.com/blog/?p=795 . This is the best which one i found till now. But it is via script not via APIs. I want to do it via Flume APIs. Please help me in this regard. And tell me steps, how to start and organize code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should maybe explain more about what you want to achieve.

The link you post appears to be just fine for your needs. You need to start a Flume agent on your client to read the files and send them using the Avro sink. Then you need a Flume agent on your server which uses an Avro source to read the events and write them where you want.

If you want to send events directly from an application then have a look at the embedded agent in Flume 1.4 or the Flume appender in log4j2 or (worse) the log4j appender in Flume.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html
You can write client to send events or use Embedded agent.
As for the code organization, it is up to you.